# @Repository in Spring 4

Tags: spring

```
@Repository
public interface userRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

There are many sites showing this way of creating DAO in Spring 4 using `JpaRepository`. `@Repository` also creating instance just like `@Component`, `@Service` etc. Container internally beans by using `new` operator while component scan (using `@Component` scan annotation) of classes having annotation  `@Component`, `@Service` etc. Then how container create instance for `@Repository` as shown above, as it is an interface which is purely abstract and we can't create instance for interface using new operator.

Comment: This isn't plain spring but Spring Data, to be specific Spring Data JPA.

Answer (score 0):

Spring will create a [SimpleJpaRepository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html) instance for declared Interfaces that extend JpaRepository.
Note: there is much more magic going on. You can add your own queries via @Query to the interface and Repositories also support transaction management. To achieve that the Repository will be wrapped in a proxy which can intercept and dynamically implement its methods.

Comment: Well no spring will create nothing, Spring Data JPA will create that and add the behavior.

Comment: He was talking about JpaRepository so it was obviously implied. And Spring Data JPA is part of Spring, so what I said is true.

Comment: Depends on what you define as Spring, Spring for most people is the Spring Framework and that is only that and doesn't include Spring Data nor any other portfolio project. Nor was the post tagged and the question was pointing at Spring and not Spring Data JPA. Regardless it still is better to be explicit then take the assumption that things are implied.